# Wordpress get ID - not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress

I am hoping that someone can help me with this relative simple problem:

```
 <?php $idairports = the_ID(); ?>

$liveposts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_airports WHERE id = ".$idairports."") );
```

It seems like I am not able to get the variable passed into the sting above.

$idairports is supposed to be a numeric value...

If I do this  `<?php echo $idairports ?>` I do get the value.

But I do not get the value here `FROM wp_airports WHERE id = ".$idairports.""`

What am I doing wrong

Thanks

Okay I have found the main problem:

```
global $wpdb;
$page_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$page_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
$idairports = $page_id;
```

It seems like I were getting `the_ID();` value the wrong way...

If I get the page_id as above, it works 100%

Can someone maybe explain why the_ID() would work if I echo the_ID() outside the MYSQL statement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quotes are screwed up and your php tags look awkward:

```
<?php 
    $idairports = the_ID();
    $liveposts = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM wp_airports WHERE id = ' . $idairports));
?>
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but it does not work.... (if I make the id value in the select statement static is seem to work)

Comment: If I make this value static $idairports = the_ID(); like $idairports = 3000; the MYSQL query seem to work. It looks like the_ID(); maybe the problem. I am not sure if it is possible, but seems to render after the sql statement.

Comment: It's not the way PHP works. If this were JavaScript, you might have an issue and would want to put that query inside a callback. What's your `the_id()` function look like?

Comment: $page_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();$page_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id(); I were figuring the the_id() is maybe a javascript result.. I have changed the way I get the id using the above, and now it is working 100% thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is with the double quotes. Try removing the quotes when referencing the id like this.

```
$liveposts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM wp_airports WHERE id = ' . $idairports) );
```

Comment: Have tried this, thanks for the quotes issue, looks like the problem is with the_ID();

Comment: Try echoing out you the_ID() function before the query is processed and see what result your getting.